# Automatic centralizing of fixed width value items in reactive containers

Tags: html, css

I have a container and items to fit in it.
The width and height values of the item are fixed.
When the screen shrinks, items should be automatically wrapped. 
Items that have been replaced should be centrally arranged based on the screen. 
I've tried display:flex, but justify-content:center attributes make the last content out of place.
How should I set this layout? Should I set the with value with Java script or media query?

i want this layout
[image]
[image]

display:flex; justify-contents:center;
[image]

Comment: flex-wrap will fix your problem  `diaplay:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content:flex-start`

Comment: I've already tried `flex-wrap:wrap;`
The container does not come to the center of the screen.
Do I have to hold the with value as fixed px instead of %?

Comment: can you post some code or running example on the code-sand box ?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you can also wrap your container components in another flex container which will have `width:100%`, and this inner container component will have `width:auto`, now on new wrapper container put `justify-content:centre;` and inner container put this CSS
`diaplay:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content:flex-start`

Comment: `Justify-content:flex-start` applied well to inner-container. By the way, if `with:auto` is applied, the with value increases as much as the number of items, so the `inline-flex` does not centralize. I think we should set a with value for the media query. Thank you.